# How do I optimize these SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have 1 variable which is used as **WHERE** condition in 3 initial queries. Based on the response from one of those I need to create queries to 2 more queries.

```
$var1 = $_GET['id']; $var2 = $_GET['truck'];
//first two are easy
SELECT `name`, `address` FROM `company` WHERE `id`='".$var1."' LIMIT 1; //q1

SELECT `value`, `date` FROM `checks` WHERE `truck`='".$var2."'; //q2

//the 3rd query may have multiple results and for every result i need **q4** and **q5** to be executed
SELECT `loadNumber`, `cfnNumber` FROM `loads` WHERE `truck`='".$var2."' ; //q3


//notice that WHERE conditions use values from **q3**
SELECT `value`, `date` FROM `finances` WHERE `load`='".loadNumber."'; //q4

SELECT `address` FROM `stops` WHERE `load`='".loadNumber."'; //q5
```

My question is about optimization as I am trying to combine all these queries into one if possible, hoping it will mean lesser server load time. I am not very familiar with JOINS, so ultimately [this](http://codepad.org/vSkMR8HS) is how my code looks like with **real** data. And [here](https://jsonblob.com/555de6e2e4b06ad9c0c422f7) is the result, also with real data. Is there a need to optimize/join these queries in order to decrease server load?

Comment: I would like to format the response in a single JSON output. Something like [http://jsonblob.com/555d192fe4b0f556a9b83829](https://jsonblob.com/555d192fe4b0f556a9b83829)

Comment: please add that sort of info to your question. not all external code/image hosting sites are available from all (stupidly filtered) locations.

Comment: what is that? this json has NOTHING common with your question

Comment: no. because mysql doesn't output json.

Comment: I'm sorry. I use array and then php's json_encode to output it in JSON format. Something like: 
`foreach($r as $item => $value){ $d["$item"] = $value;}
$all['d'] = $d; 
print json_encode($all);`

Comment: So how table `company` is related to any other table?

Comment: It is not, but i'm trying to put everything in 1 query.

Comment: Why? I would suggest to combine just last 3 queries, keep first 2 as is

Comment: Ok. Can you please put your suggestion in an answer? I'm new to joins.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to combine just last 3 queries, keep first 2 as is:

```
SELECT 
  l.`loadNumber`, l.`cfnNumber` , 
  f.`value`, f.`date`,
  s.`address`
FROM `loads` l
LEFT JOIN `finances` f
ON f.`load`= l.loadNumber
LEFT JOIN `stops` s
ON s.`load`= l.loadNumber
WHERE `truck`='".$var2."'
```

Comment: Thank you! I think think this will work for me. Can you please tell me why do you think it would be better to keep the first 2 separate? Isn't it always better to have as least queries as possible?

Comment: No. It is better to have as many queries as you really need. In your case tables have nothing common - that is why I see no reason to combine them

Comment: I really appreciate your answer as it helped me understand joins a little better. However i unmarked it as selected because ultimately it didn't work for me. Here's my working code: http://codepad.org/m8hr6Dol and the result: https://jsonblob.com/555de6e2e4b06ad9c0c422f7. If you have any optimization suggestions, your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Do a subquery. Be something like this:

```
SELECT `item1_t1`, `item2_t1` FROM `table1` WHERE `item2_t1` in (SELECT `item1_t2` FROM `table2` WHERE `item2_t2`='".$var."');
```